# Understanding media queries with a simple example

Tags: css, media-queries

I thought media queries are really really easy.
[Codepen of the problem](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Evyxr)

css

```
.outer{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 1500px;
}

.flipcardscontainer{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 622px) {
    .flipcardscontainer{
        width: 506px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 422) {
    .flipcardscontainer{
        width: 306px !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 405px) {
    .flipcardscontainer{
        width: 206px !important;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="flipcardscontainer"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I want is that the blue square that is around the red square is always visible. Now I start dragging the window size from 400 slowly upwards to 750. It does not behave at all like I expect.

the square with the class flipcardscontainer is, looking at the css, always smaller than the device screen width, which is the browser width, right?

The only query that seems to work is `@media only screen and (max-width : 405px)`

Why is the result not as expected?

Comment: I think you forgot the "px" on 422.. and you dont have a media query working between widths 405px and 422px; and try rearranging your media queries, put the (min-width: 622px) below the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) I think you forgot the "px" on 422. 
2.) You dont have a media query working between widths 405px and 422px. 
3.) Rearrange your breakpoints, put the one with `(min-width: 622px)` **below** the others      because the css rules at breakpoint `(min-width : 422px)` is overriding it when the viewport width is >622px.

Doing so will give you **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/UN4xJ/)**

Answer (score 1):

**[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sofam/1/edit)**

You have two media-queries which are using the same condition.

For one of the media-query, Insert the max-width and try. It will work.

You also forgot px in second condition

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 622px) {
    .flipcardscontainer{
        width: 506px !important;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-width : 422px) and (max-width: 621px) {
    .flipcardscontainer{
        width: 306px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 405px) {
    .flipcardscontainer{
        width: 206px !important;

    }
}
```

Comment: the nice thing is this works like css. So you actually don't have to be exclusive if the newer definition (the one further down) wins. Which is, best achieved an descending max-width definition or an ascending min-width definition. You have a typo as well, you forgot px in your 422 definition

Comment: Yes, your codepen had typo for 422 definition. That's why it didn't work

Comment: @Toskan Added demo link. You can check it in jsbin

Comment: +1 yours is perfectly fine, thanks. I just think that using the cascading way is nicer than excluding. That + the missing px he found, So I accepted the other post.